# The difference of "score" for the two periods for each id

Tags: r

I want to make the difference of "score" for the two periods for each id.

```
   id <- rep(1:3,each=2)
period <- rep(1:2,3)
score <- c(3,2,4,1,8,5)

df <- data.frame(id, period,score)
df
id period score
1      1     3
1      2     2
2      1     4
2      2     1
3      1     8
3      2     5
```

I was thinking to first group by id but then I should also group by period and then sum for score.How do I do this?

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
```

It should look like

```
 id score
     1     1
     2     3
     3     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `diff` after grouping by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(score = abs(diff(score)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id score
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     2     3
#3     3     3
```

---

Or in `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(score ~ id, df, diff)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your desired output, you are looking to substract period2 from period 1, am I right ?

If so, I don't think you can call that the average. 
One possible solution is to do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = period, values_from = score) %>%
    mutate(Avg = `1` - `2`) %>% select(id, Avg)
```

An another possibility is to assign a negative number to score for period  2 and then sum the score for each id:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(score = ifelse(period == 2, score*-1, score)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>% summarise(Score = sum(score))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id Score
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     3
3     3     3
```